# I have some problem with the bevel tool

Tags: bevel

I was trying to emulate Default Cube doing an old looking book, but when I tried to make the rounded part of the cover there is some problem: in the video the 2 selected edges converge in a different point.

(What the result should look like)
[image]

(What is my result)
[image]

As you can see the edges in the example converge closer to the left part of the book, my first attempt is to resize the shape, but this doesn't make any improvement.
Maybe is something stupid, but I don't know how to solve my problem

Comment: Apply scale of the object with Ctrl+A

Comment: Agree with Alan, the problem is non-uniform scale. If you scale a mesh in Object mode, you must tell blender to "reset" the object's scale with the above mentioned method, otherwise you will have problems with insets, bevels, shading, etc...

Comment: It works, thank you very much, I don't understand how to make the answer as final solution

Comment: this one will probably be closed as a duplicate, @bl4nk, but thank you for the question